# Searching for files in Google Drive API with Variables

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to list specific file using google drive. I want to find files that are between two dates that are stored in variables. I know that the query format is along these lines

```
service.files().list().setQ("fullText contains 'Volunteers'");
```

but instead of it being fullText contains volunteers. I want it to be something like

```
service.files().list().setQ("fullText >= 'date1' and fullText <= 'date2'");
```

and of course date1 and date2 being the date variable storing the date.

If anyone knows a way to do this it would be great

Comment: Sorry about the original wrong title everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to searching by dates, [Google Drive search docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters), supports last-modified-time and last-viewed-time. It also states that:

> "Fields of type date are not currently comparable to each other, only
>   to constant dates."

Sample:

```
modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00' // default time zone is UTC
modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'
```

Comment: So, this means that I cannot compare the time to a variable even if i put the string/date into the default time of utc right? It cannot be a variable? Sorry I just want to be clear

Comment: It appears to be so. You can always try with code to confirm it :)